# Visual Studio error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _fgetc_unlocked

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to use libjasper from http://www.ece.uvic.ca/~frodo/jasper/ as a static library in compiling dcraw.c from http://www.cybercom.net/~dcoffin/dcraw/ on windows with VC9. I have resolved several issues on the way and finally get three linking errors.

```
1>dcraw.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ftello
1>dcraw.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _fseeko
1>dcraw.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _getc_unlocked
```

the first two of these are easily resolved it seems, I added

```
#define fseeko _fseeki64
#define ftello _ftelli64
```

and that does it but what about the third one:

```
1>dcraw.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _getc_unlocked
```

How can I work around that on windows with visual studio?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual equivalent of `getc_unlocked` is not `getc`, it's `_fgetc_nolock`. So, assuming that whoever wrote the original code knew what he's doing and had some reasons to prefer the thread-unsafe version, you probably want *this*:

```
#define getc_unlocked _fgetc_nolock
```

Comment: Aha, there's a real equivalent. Why do Microsoft have to give everything non-standard names? Upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define getc_unlocked _fgetc_nolock
```

Only difference is that `getc` is thread-safe (and probably slower).

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/getc_unlocked.html

EDIT: As @Fanael pointed out in another answer, `_fgetc_nolock` makes for a better replacement than `getc`.

Comment: doesn't getc_unlocked take a FILE*?

Answer (score 0):

It's a posix function not on win32, just do

`#define getc_unlocked fgetc`

Answer (score 0):

Replace calls to `getc` and `getc_unlocked` with `fgetc` when compiling for Windows.

I vaguely remember ftello, fseeko and possibly getc_unlocked as being specific to linux/gcc/posix.

getc is roughly prototyped as `int getc( FILE* f);`

fgetc is roughly prototyped as `int fgetc( FILE* f );`

and, in fact, in MSVS 10, getc is a define for fgetc.